# How to get all Nodes from a specific Model (libgdx)

Tags: java, arrays, 3d, libgdx

I was trying to get all the Nodes from the Sphere I created and used the following code.

```
private Array<Node> nodes;

    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    Model model = modelBuilder.createSphere(10, 10, 10, 20, 20, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED)), Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
    nodes = model.nodes;

    for (Iterator<Node> iterator = nodes.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        Node node = (Node) iterator.next();
        nodes.add(node);
    }
```

In my opinion this should return all the Nodes.
In fact `nodes.size` is "1" regardless of the Spheres size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, `Model#nodes` provides direct access to the (`Array` of) root nodes. `ModelBuilder` only creates rootnodes, so in your case that will be all nodes of the model. The `createSphere` method always creates one node, regardless the size (dimensions) of the sphere (although I'm not sure why you'd think that would be related?)

If you like, [this tutorial](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/behind-the-3d-scenes-part1/) explains the Model structure in depth.